# Implementation: Algorithm for a special distribution Problem

Tags: algorithm

We are given a number *x*, and a set of *n* coins with denominations *v*<sub>1</sub>, *v*<sub>2</sub>, …, *v*<sub>*n*</sub>.

The coins are to be divided between Alice and Bob, with the restriction that each person's coins must add up to at least *x*.

For example, if *x* = 1, *n* = 2, and *v*<sub>1</sub> = *v*<sub>2</sub> = 2, then there are two possible distributions: one where Alice gets coin #1 and Bob gets coin #2, and one with the reverse. (These distributions are considered distinct even though both coins have the same denomination.)

I'm interested in counting the possible distributions. I'm pretty sure this can be done in *O*(*nx*) time and *O*(*n*+*x*) space using dynamic programming; but I don't see how.

Comment: when are 2 distributions different? By values or by coin indexes?

Comment: @juvian Coin indexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Count the ways for one person to get just less than x, double it and subtract from the doubled total number of ways to divide the collection in two, (Stirling number of the second kind `{n, 2}`).

For example,

```
{2, 3, 3, 5}, x = 5

i  matrix
0  2: 1
1  3: 1 (adding to 2 is too much)
2  3: 2
3  N/A (≥ x)

3 ways for one person to get
less than 5.

Total ways to partition a set
of 4 items in 2 is {4, 2} = 7

2 * 7 - 2 * 3 = 8
```

The Python code below uses MBo's routine. If you like this answer, please consider up-voting that answer.

```py
# Stirling Algorithm
# Cod3d by EXTR3ME
# https://extr3metech.wordpress.com
def stirling(n,k):
  n1=n
  k1=k
  if n<=0:
    return 1
  elif k<=0:
    return 0   
  elif (n==0 and k==0):
    return -1
  elif n!=0 and n==k:
    return 1
  elif n<k:
    return 0
  else:
    temp1=stirling(n1-1,k1)
    temp1=k1*temp1
    return (k1*(stirling(n1-1,k1)))+stirling(n1-1,k1-1)

def f(coins, x):
  a = [1] + (x-1) * [0]

  # Code by MBo
  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/53418438/2034787
  for c in coins:
      for i in xrange(x - 1, c - 1, -1):
          if a[i - c] > 0:
              a[i] = a[i] + a[i - c]

  return 2 * (stirling(len(coins), 2) - sum(a) + 1)

print f([2,3,3,5], 5) # 8
print f([1,2,3,4,4], 5) # 16
```

Comment: Nice catch concerning non-significant nominals!

Comment: How exactly do you count count the ways for one person to get just less than x ?

Comment: @faegra MBo described such a method. Can you think of how to modify it to achieve this?

Comment: great answer. I think the uncommon case of sum of elements being < 2x should be handled separately

Comment: @juvian I think so! If the sum of elements < 2x the answer is always 0 or?

Comment: @faegra yup, 0 is the answer

Answer (score 3):

If sum of all coins is `S`, then the first person can get `x..S-x` of money.

Make array `A` of length `S-x+1` and fill it with numbers of variants of changing `A[i]` with given coins (like kind of Coin Change problem).

To provide uniqueness (don't count `C1+C2` and `C2+C1` as two variants), fill array in reverse direction

```
A[0] = 1
for C in Coins:
    for i = S-x downto C:
        if A[i - C] > 0:
             A[i] = A[i] + A[i - C] 
             //we can compose value i as i-C and C
```

then sum `A` entries in range `x..S-x`

Example for coins `2, 3, 3, 5` and `x=5`.
`S = 13, S-x = 8`

Array state after using coins in order:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  //idx
1   1
1   1 1   1
1   1 2   2 1   1 
1   1 2   3 1 1 3
```

So there are 8 variants to distribute these coins. Quick check (3' denotes the second coin 3):

```
2 3      3' 5
2 3'     3 5
2 3 3'   5  
2 5      3 3'
3 3'     2 5
3 5      2 3'
3' 5     2 3
5        2 3 3'
```

Comment: But that needs O(S-x+1) space instead of O(n+x). Is there a way to improve this? Also, the runtime is bigger than O(nx),

Comment: This approach cannot be improved as-is, but @גלעד ברקן proposed inversion - instead of calculation for `0..S-x` interval make calculation for complementary `0..x` interval

Answer (score 3):

You can also solve it in O(A * x^2) time and memory adding memoization to this dp:

```
solve(A, pos, sum1, sum2):
    if (pos == A.length) return sum1 == x && sum2 == x
    return solve(A, pos + 1, min(sum1 + A[pos], x), sum2) + 
           solve(A, pos + 1, sum1, min(sum2 + A[pos], x))

print(solve(A, 0, 0, 0))
```

So depending if x^2 < sum or not you could use this or the answer provided by @Mbo (in terms of time complexity). If you care more about space, this is better only when A * x^2 < sum - x

Comment: UV for alternative. Seems the last argument is missed in the first recursive call. And is `==x` correct here?

Comment: It's ==x because we never have values over x. Code was wrong using max instead of min, fixed ^^ @MBo

Comment: @juvian What are the dimensions fo A?

Comment: @faegra A in the code is the array of coins, in the complexity is the amount of coins, a bit of notation abuse ^^

Comment: @juvian I am a bit confused. Where exactly is the solution displayed? At the end sum1 == x && sum2 == x will output but this is a boolean and not the solution?

Comment: @faegra in many languages false is considered 0 and true is considered 1, you could replace that with if (sum1 == x && sum2 == x) {return 1} else {return 0}. For the real solution, you would need to call solve(A, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: @MBo a bit lost, what did you try?